What does "getting someone done" mean?
In Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023), after he questioned King Hale if Henry, being Mollie's first husband,
still has rights over the family, Ernest meets Ramsey:

Ernest: King Bill Hale wants to know if you'd like a job
getting someone done.
Ramsey: Oh, I can't do that. I didn't sign on for that kind of work.

What does "getting someone done" mean ?

I don't see your cited text anywhere in the movie subtitles, but almost certainly King Bill Hale wants to know if Ramsey is willing take on a job as a hitman (get someone done = kill them). Compare "I'' do you!" = "I'll kill you" (or punish you severely; context is everything).

"do" can mean attack or kill.
